# Means of groups A and B differ significantly. Can I build a Classifier that will classify values into A or B?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, classification, t-test

With regard to [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/16800/6637) about classifications of groups which differ significantly, I have two somewhat newbie / general questions:

1. Lets say I'm doing a hypothesis test (the difference between two means) and I reject the null with 95% confidence (alpha = 0.05). Does this imply that I can predict/classify new values into A or B with a success rate of 95% ? If so, how this can be done ?
2. Not sure in what realm my question would fall, but does this somehow relate to the [explanatory vs predictive modeling](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/18896/6637) discussion ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. No, unfortunately not.  To see why not, consider class A as being drawn from a Normal(0,1) distribution and class B as being drawn from a Normal(0.01,1) distribution.  The two are virtually indistinguishable on an observation-by-observation basis, so, without other information, you'll not be able to assign an observation to A or B with a success rate of much over 50%.  However, if your sample size is large enough, say 100,000, you'll have little problem rejecting the null hypothesis that the two means are the same if you test at the 95% level.  (Whether or not you *should* test at the 95% level with a sample size of 100,000 is a different question.)
2. That's an excellent question, and the answer seems to me to be yes.  Assume A vs B is some factor related to the outcome; we can see that A vs B makes a (small) difference to the outcome, but knowing that is of very little help for prediction.